# How can i add a module to a maven multi-project for sonar?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i have a Maven multi project with several modules in the pom.xml.
But for the sonar-Scan i want to use other modules (includes and excludes)!

The property-file (sonar-project.properties) is not used in Maven-Projects, so the properties sonar.modules and xxx.sonar.projectBaseDir are not working.

How can i configure it with Maven?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain more? It would be best to include the layout of your Maven project and its submodules, and explain in those terms your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Maven profiles to include only specific modules: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>all</id>
        <modules>
            <module>module-A</module>
            <module>module-B</module>
            <module>module-C</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <modules>
            <module>module-A</module>
            <module>module-C</module>
            <module>module-D</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Execute `mvn -Psonar clean package sonar:sonar`

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: I thought it worked, but if I remove a module from the profile, it will still be analyzed. Any Ideas?